dpkg Error: 'start-stop-daemon' Not Found in PATH or Not Executable
I’m experiencing an issue with dpkg on my Ubuntu system. When I try to perform certain package management tasks, I receive the following error
dpkg: warning: 'start-stop-daemon' not found in PATH or not executable
dpkg: error: 1 expected program not found in PATH or not executable
Details:
Ubuntu Version:  Ubuntu 22.04.4LTS
Issue: I’m unable to complete package installations or upgrades due to the dpkg error indicating that start-stop-daemon is either not found or not executable.
Steps Taken: I’ve tried updating the package lists, reinstalling dpkg, and checking for the start-stop-daemon file in /usr/sbin, but the issue persists.
Commands Attempted:
    sudo apt-get update
    sudo apt-get upgrade
    sudo dpkg --configure -a
    sudo apt-get install --reinstall dpkg
    sudo apt-get install --reinstall start-stop-daemon

Additional Information:
The directory /usr/sbin appears to be missing from the PATH for some commands.
I’ve checked the system files and tried to reinstall core packages without success.

Request:
Could anyone provide guidance on how to resolve this issue? Are there specific steps I should follow to fix the start-stop-daemon problem, or is there a way to repair my Ubuntu installation to address this issue?

@kos since the commands were run with sudo, the default Ubuntu sudoers env_reset configuration would export PATH equal to the specified secure_path, no?

@steeldriver as always I miss very important details, so I'll make it PATH=$PATH:/usr/sbin sudo --preserve-env=PATH <command> and change my suggestion to "check out secure_path in /etc/sudoers", it appears as though something could be wrong with that? Thanks for pointing that out!

... programatically, they could use sudo -l to check the value of secure_path for their user, and/or sudo sh -c 'echo "$PATH"' to verify that it is actually being applied
